# Please tell me what's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion

I wonder why people closed and want to delete it? It received several answers, although neither is satisfying. Possibly such word does not exist in English.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93618/really-black-people/93620

So far it received 4 upvotes and 1 downvote. It proved impossible to find an answer in a dictionary.

I had been already banned from this site twice be the moderator. I am not sure now whether I ever can ask any question here - they all get closed immediately.

Comment: Maybe that question didn't offend any explicitly-stated site rules, but it offended my sensibilities. Even so, I waited an hour or two before closevoting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what sensibilities?

Comment: I personally don't have a big problem with "the n-word", but it's probably fair to say *mulatto* bothers me a lot more than *nigger* bothers many others. That's simply because *nigger* can be seen as having become offensive over time (from neutral/descriptive L. *niger*, thru *negro*). But so far as I'm concerned, *mulatto* never had roots in anything other than "genetic impurity", so it's ***always*** been offensive. Besides which, justifiably or not, I don't like your phrasing *"people whose skin isn’t really that black"*. It sounds far too much like *"people who aren't really that bad"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not know that the word is offensive in English, but does it mean that questions about potentially oofensive words are forbidden?

Comment: You've been on ELU almost two years, so you know the answer to that one perfectly well - you're simply being provocative/disingenuous. I think I'm starting to understand why the mods might have banned you before. Perhaps you did truly ask that question on main in good faith, but I'm starting to think otherwise. You've still offered no "real-world reason" for asking it, and it looks increasingly less likely to me that you actually *have* any (non-offensive, non-racist) motivation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers LOL. My native language is Russian, I do not know what words are racist in Englkish. "Mulat" is not offensive in Russian. "Mulatka" song by a popular Russian singer  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGEG6wdlHAM

Comment: If you ask the question, and then fail to remove offensive language, argue with people's answers, and tell them straight out that their reasonably correct answers (*"ebony", "very dark skin"*) are wrong, when you obviously don't know enough to judge whether they are or not, you are not going to be well-received here.

Answer (score 1):

Anixx, you asked a racially-charged question that got at least four helpful comments and four answers. What makes you think that you can't ask a question here?

Moreover, I've looked at some of your recent questions that were closed. They all seem scant on details: very little details on why the question is being asked, where the language came from, or what research you've already done.

This isn't the first time I've pointed people to Yoichi's questions, and it probably won't be the last.  But, compare [this question of yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83728/does-the-word-government-in-english-mean-the-courts-as-well) with [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93316/is-something-in-the-sand-a-popular-english-phrase) of his.

Or [this question of yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83729/fill-an-appeal-or-file-an-appeal) with [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93522/whats-the-difference-between-take-yes-for-an-answer-and-say-yes-for-an-answe) of his.

Or [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/are-monkeys-a-subset-of-apes) with [that one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93224/who-are-them-in-the-sentence-awards-honorees-were-a-group-of-upending-types-w).

What differences do you see?  I see one set of questions with meticulous details about context, along with earnest research that is methodically presented.  In other words, one set of questions clearly caters to a community of serious experts, while the other questions don't.

I suggest you spend more time researching each one of your own questions before asking it here. Try to find the answer yourself. And I don't just mean a quick look in a dictionary; do web searches as well. Invest a significant amount of your own time and effort. Then, if you still haven't figured out a satisfactory answer to your question, compose a carefully crafted a question for ELU, taking diligent care to integrate the results of your prior research into your question, explaining why you are still confused.

I suspect that a question researched and presented in that fashion would be much more warmly received.

Comment: I think it is also unhelpful that Anixx seems to insist that "ebony" is a light color while the rest of us are telling him it is a dark color and also that "dark-skinned" doesn't mean black when we all agree that it does.

Comment: @KitFox: I'd agree; obstinacy rarely helps one's cause, and can sometimes prompt a flurry of downvotes and close votes instead.

Comment: @J.R. it was closed before I commented on the "ebony" answers.

Comment: @Anixx: I think you're misunderstanding my point. You wondered aloud if you could ask a question on here. I'm saying that, despite the fact that your question could be construed as offensive or politically incorrect, it still got about 8 helpful responses. You seem more offended that your question was closed than thankful that several people took time to answer your question.  Moreover, you "wonder why people close and want to delete your questions." Wonder no more: they are being closed because they are of **low quality**.

Comment: @J.R. I see. Still if it was not closed there probably would be more helpful anbswers. Moreover I feel this question does not offend any site's rules, but one more closed question of mine increases probability of me being banned again.

Comment: _"If it was not closed there probably would be more helpful answers."_ Perhaps so, but I prefer that you concentrate on the corollary: _"Had the question been a better question, it probably would not have been closed."_

Comment: @J.R. so how is it possible to improve it? It is exact and contains all necessary information for an answer.

Comment: @Anixx: Did you check the links that I provided above? Did you not see how he included the info found from prior research? What - aside from Googling "ebony" with your SafeSearch off - kind of research did you do? Did you consult a thesaurus? Examine any word lists like [this one](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/Words-used-to-describe-skin-colour)? And why are you asking this question? You provided no background information.   Hover over the downvote button and read what it says: _no research effort, unclear, not useful_. That describes your question rather well.